# Serverless Framework / Lambda Errors on External Http Calls

Tags: async-await, axios, serverless-framework, serverless

I wrote a simple service with Serverless Framework deployed to AWS Lambda that makes a call to an External Http Service and returns the results.

Currently the service works fine locally, but does not work when deployed to AWS.

There seems to be some problem with the async call resolve on response. If I remove the external http call the simple hello function works fine remotely.

**Here is some code for review:**

https://github.com/kevbaker/serverless-typescript-call-mock-api

**Here is a snippet of the handler:**

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, Callback, Context, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import axios from 'axios';

export const hello: Handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context, cb: Callback) => {

  // External Http call with Axios
  let URL:string = "https://demo8946897.mockable.io";
  let mockResponse = await axios.get(URL,{});

  // Send response
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      message: 'Go Serverless Webpack (Typescript) v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      mockResponse: mockResponse.data
    },
  };
  cb(null, response);
}
```

Any thoughts? I've done a bunch of poking around for this issue. Change to Fetch-node, reviewed logs no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

With the await syntax available now for Node in Lambda, you can make some changes that better fit that style. For example you no longer need a callback and you can directly return the response object. This may solve your problem:

```
export const hello: Handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context) => {

  // External Http call with Axios
  let URL:string = "https://demo8946897.mockable.io";
  let mockResponse = await axios.get(URL,{});

  // Send response
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless Webpack (Typescript) v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      mockResponse: mockResponse.data
    }),
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth. I updated the code on github to use your version. This doesn't seem to fix it :( Also when I used the `return` syntax, it doesn't seem to return the response object on the local invoke, which is strange because I have actually used that syntax in most my other code.

Updated code: https://github.com/kevbaker/serverless-typescript-call-mock-api

Comment: @KevinBaker I updated my answer to include stringify. I was actually debating with myself whether I had to or not at the time of writing the answer. Obviously my 50/50 decision didn't go my way hehe

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to wrap the response body with `JSON.stringify`. The response body *must* be a string. I had nested objects in my axios result that I was including in my function response as `mockResponse`.

```
export const hello: Handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context) => {

  // External Http call with Axios
  let URL:string = "https://demo8946897.mockable.io";
  let mockResponse = await axios.get(URL,{});

  // Send response
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless Webpack (Typescript) v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      mockResponse: mockResponse.data
    })
  };
}
```